# what is difference between HttpCacheability.NoCache and HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

What is difference between

- HttpCacheability.NoCache
- HttpCacheability.Server
- HttpCacheability.Public
- HttpCacheability.Private
- HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache

At which condition we should use which one?

Comment: MSDN page about HttpCacheability explains this topic very well.They also provide a link to complete W3C specification (if you need more details).

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability(v=vs.110).aspx)

- NoCache :

  > Sets the Cache-Control: no-cache header. Without a field name, the directive applies to the entire request and a shared (proxy server) cache must force a successful revalidation with the origin Web server before satisfying the request. With a field name, the directive applies only to the named field; the rest of the response may be supplied from a shared cache.
- Private

  > Default value. Sets Cache-Control: private to specify that the response is cacheable only on the client and not by shared (proxy server) caches.
- Public

  > Sets Cache-Control: public to specify that the response is cacheable by clients and shared (proxy) caches.
- Server

  > Specifies that the response is cached only at the origin server. Similar to the NoCache option. Clients receive a Cache-Control: no-cache directive but the document is cached on the origin server. Equivalent to ServerAndNoCache.
- ServerAndNoCache

  > Applies the settings of both Server and NoCache to indicate that the content is cached at the server but all others are explicitly denied the ability to cache the response.
- ServerAndPrivate

  > Indicates that the response is cached at the server and at the client but nowhere else. Proxy servers are not allowed to cache the response.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, i read it already but i want to know in simple words!

Comment: Is there no option to cache both publicly on clients, and on the server? Or will `Public` also cache on the server?

Comment: @RuudLenders sounds like you want `ServerAndPrivate`

Answer (score 2):

```
NoCache: nobody can cache the page.
Private: only browsers can cache it (but not shared proxies). This is the default value
Public: everybody can cache the page, proxies included
Server: pages are cached only on the server (like the NoCache, so browsers don't cache the page)
ServerAndNoCache: pages are cached only on the server (like the NoCache, so browsers don't cache the page)
ServerAndPrivate: only browsers can cache it (but not shared proxies).
```

You can read more here:

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/04/01/Beware-the-ASP.NET-SetCacheability-method.aspx